# Hiding empty cart in Shopify

Tags: shopify, hidden, cart

I'm trying to hide my cart when it is empty and found my cart code snippet in the header.liquid file

```
<a href="/cart" class="site-header__cart">
{% include 'icon-cart' %}
<span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'layout.cart.title' | t }}</span>
<span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'layout.cart.title' | t }}</span>
{% if cart.item_count > 0 %}
<div id="CartCount" class="site-header__cart-count">
<span>{{ cart.item_count }}</span>
<span class="icon__fallback-text medium-up--hide">{{ 'layout.cart.items_count' | t: count: cart.item_count }}</span>
</div>
{% endif %}
</a>
```

I've also tried using this code that I found here (https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/hide-cart-checkout-button-when-cart-is-empty-115075)

```
{% if cart.item_count != 0 %}
```

Both of these aren't working for me, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code, do let us know if this help you to resolve your query:

```
{% if cart.item_count > 0 %} your html here {% endif %}
```

Also you need to make some changes to js if your page in not refreshing during add to cart if your theme using ajax add to cart functionality.

Thanks

Comment: That's what I'm using but the cart is displaying when it's empty

Comment: It's working now thank you!

    {% if cart.item_count > 0 %}
    <a href="/cart" class="site-header__cart">
    {% include 'icon-cart' %}
    <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'layout.cart.title' | t }}</span>
    <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'layout.cart.title' | t }}</span>
    <div id="CartCount" class="site-header__cart-count">
    <span>{{ cart.item_count }}</span>
    <span class="icon__fallback-text medium-up--hide">{{ 'layout.cart.items_count' | t: count: cart.item_count }}</span>
    </div>
    </a>
    {% endif %}